# Select GeoJSON features with a mouse interaction - OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers-3, geojson

I have GeoJSON features that consists of many little features. When I hover over one of them, I want the whole layer to be selected and not only a part of my layer.

I don't know where to start to achieve that... anyone can help me ?

This is my code for the moment:

```
var hoverClick = new ol.interaction.Select({
      condition: ol.events.condition.pointerMove, 
  });   

  select = hoverClick;
  olMap.addInteraction(select);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `ol.interaction.Select`, you could listen to the map `pointermove` event and use the `ol.Map#forEachFeatureAtPixel` method.  If there's a feature (from your layer) at the location of the pointer, then apply the wanted style to the layer.